# Boot time of 30 seconds with NVMe M.2 970 EVO SSD installed

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd

I just build my PC today and installed a fresh copy of windows on my M.2 970 EVO SSD. I have an Z390 AORUS MASTER from Gigabyte with an i7 9700k and 24gb of DDR4 RAM.

For some reason it takes windows around 30 to 40 seconds to boot from complete shut down. 
Why does it take so long? I see people with the same SSD boot within 10 seconds.

I changed ErP to disabled in BIOS (so my mouse won't shine RGB all over my bedroom). And set Fast Boot to Ultra Fast, doesn't really make a difference tho.

I also have another SSD installed and a 2TB Hybrid HDD. Both completely formatted today, so nothing is on there (except the first stuff I downloaded).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was way to quick to post here. After doing 4-5 complete restarts (with complete shut down) and now I get boot times with around 9 seconds.

If you face similar problems please try this.